# Is there a way to convert GUI in image to html?

Tags: html, user-interface, image, converters

i have this GUI screen shots from the design team which i needs to convert to a web page and what not. i'm thinking of finding some website which resembles the GUI so that i can copy and paste the html so i don't have to start from scratch. the only drawback about this method is i don't know what website actually looks like that so that might means a lot of browsing time. hehe.

So just wondering if there's a tool which can help me do the search? Or even better yet if there's a tool which can convert image into html web page equivalent, that would be even better.

i guess i'm just another lazy uncreative programmer trying to get the gui part done quick and dirty, hehe.

thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a toll for converting image to HTML

Comment: I'm not sure why you call yourself an "uncreative programmer".  Your design team has done the "creative" part, all you have to do is implement it.  "Lazy" sounds about right though ;-)  If that trait runs in the company I'd ask your designer what site they ripped off.  Otherwise something like Dreamweaver or Expression Blend might help.

Comment: hehe, just following the main values of perl to the core :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean you have a PNG, GIF or JPG screen-shot... and you want to feed that into a program and have it spit out a collection of HTML and CCS which when viewed in a browser would look just like that image?

I'm sorry to burst your bubble, but I would be very, very, very surprised if this was the case.

It's basically just impossible.  If you see a box on the screen, it could be a text area, or a div, or a td, or a gif, or any one of fifteen different things.  There's no way at all a program could every figure out which HTML element to use.

I'm sorry, but you're going to have to write HTML yourself.  A tool like Dreamweaver will help speed the process if you're new to HTML.  But I'll bet ya two bits to a farthing that there's nothing on the planet which will automate this job.

Not the answer you wanted, sorry.  But it's the answer.

Comment: hehe, yea, but for that 2seconds, the dream was worth it. :)

Comment: Dreamweaver - won't automate it completely - but it will allow you to select parts of an image and specifiy if they are text areas or image areas - the images areas are cut out and laid out in HTML and the text areas are left for you to put the text in. I never mentioned automated - but I think this is a quick process and as close to automated as you need.

Comment: Grouchal's idea is the best answer to the question. You wanna be lazy? Dreamweaver/Fireworks will cheat by spitting out lots of tables, then you just add text in and make things editable. It's not the prettiest HTML but OP doesn't seem to care about the quality of the HTML. Anybody that cared would not ask this question :)

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that you can use Adobe Dreamweaver to do this - going from design to HTML.

Comment: mmm, time to put dreamweaver and how-to into google to good use again, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that they used Fireworks to do the design. Is that [Adobe Fireworks](http://www.adobe.com/products/fireworks/features/)? If so, that application has the option of outputting the design into HTML for you.

From the feature list:

*Design once, deploy to many platforms*

*Output Fireworks designs to HTML or the application of your choice: Adobe Flash, Adobe AIR™, or Adobe Flex®. Craft custom skins with exceptional design tools. Now your tools will play well together. Design within Fireworks and then export standards-compliant CSS-based layouts — complete with external style sheets — to Dreamweaver CS4. Create components in Fireworks for use in Adobe Flex Builder™ software. Create HTML-based Adobe AIR prototypes directly from Fireworks.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any tool that can convert an image of a GUI into the equivalent HTML. I would imagine that would be very dependent on the styling of the GUI anyway. On top of that, it would probably produce some pretty nasty and nightmarish-to-maintain HTML.

It's probably not the answer you want to hear, but I'd start coding.

Did the design team do the design in HTML? Photoshop mockups? Both of those would give you a better shot at avoiding hand-coding time.

Comment: nah, already check with em, they did it with their mad fireworks skillz. so i'm left to fend for myself :(

Answer (score 0):

From a screenshot?

You probably don't wanna do this. You want probably want, at minimum, the file saved as jpeg or png, or any format, preferably with no compression so you dont lose quality.

Then you can slice it. Google "photoshop slicing tutorial" and tons will appear.

At best, you want the PSD file, which you can then slide it up and hide/show layers of things you dont want, etc.

Comment: yea, but at the end comes development time i still need to put in the effort to setup the whole html, etc, so i was thinking of ways to cheat, must be the perl programmer in me talking :P

Comment: If you slice it up in photoshop, it you can save it as HTML. What I was saying was, to do this from a screenshot is a bad choice because you probably lose quality. You want to do this with a PSD or original JPG/PNG file :)

Comment: Because I literally am interpreting the term "screenshot" as someone pressing "prt scrn", opening mspaint, pasting it and saving.